# image upload with pdo

Tags: php, image, pdo, upload

I have two input image insertion fields;
Adding one deletes the other.
If I add both, there is no problem.
but when i upload one, the other one doesn't keep the old image
when i upload two pictures to it it saves without any problem.
There are many ways to add bulk images and upload them with ajax.
but I couldn't find an answer in the form of the code I wrote

```html
<head>

</head>
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <div class="">
        <div class="page-title">
            <div class="title_left">
                <h3>Orta Haber</h3>
            </div>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Orta Haber Düzenleme <small>
                        <?php 
                        if ($_GET['durum']=='ok') {?> 

                            <b style="color:green;">Güncelleme başarılı...</b>

                        <?php } elseif ($_GET['durum']=='no')  {?>

                            <b style="color:red;">Güncelleme yapılamadı...</b>

                            <?php } ?></small> </h2>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">




                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="x_content">

                            <form action="../netting/islem.php" method="POST" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" for="first-name">İmage Adı<span class="">*</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                        <input type="text" id="image_adi" name="image_adi" value="<?php echo $imagecek['image_adi']; ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
               

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name"><span class=""></span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">                    
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Video Resmi<span class=""></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                        <?php 
                    if (strlen($imagecek['image1'])>0) {?>

                    <img width="150"  src="../../<?php echo $imagecek['image1']; ?>">

                    <?php } else {?>


                    <img width="150"  src="../../dimg/kullanici-resim-yok.jpg">


                    <?php } ?>
                                        <input type="file" id="image1" name="image1" value="<?php echo $imagecek['image1']; ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Video Resmi<span class=""></span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                        <?php 
                    if (strlen($imagecek['image2'])>0) {?>

                    <img width="150"  src="../../<?php echo $imagecek['image2']; ?>">

                    <?php } else {?>


                    <img width="150"  src="../../dimg/kullanici-resim-yok.jpg">


                    <?php } ?>
                                        <input type="file" id="image2" name="image2" value="<?php echo $imagecek['image2']; ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div align="right" class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">

                                    <button type="submit" name="imagekaydet" class="btn btn-primary">Güncelle</button>
                                </div>

                            </form>



                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /page content -->



<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

islem.php

```html
if (isset($_POST['imagekaydet'])) {


    if (!empty($_FILES['image1'])) {
        $uploads_dir1 = 'images/';

        $tmp_name1 = $_FILES['image1']["tmp_name"];
        $name1 = $_FILES['image1']["name"];
        $refimgyol1=substr($uploads_dir1, 6)."images/".$name1;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name1, "$uploads_dir1/$name1");

        $ayarkaydet=$db->prepare("UPDATE image SET
            image_adi=:image_adi,
            image1=:image1
            WHERE image_id=1");
        $update=$ayarkaydet->execute(array(
            'image_adi' => $_POST['image_adi'],
            'image1' => $refimgyol1
        ));
    }
        

if (!empty($_FILES['image2'])) {
    $uploads_dir2 = 'images/';

        $tmp_name2 = $_FILES['image2']["tmp_name"];
        $name2 = $_FILES['image2']["name"];
        $refimgyol2=substr($uploads_dir2, 6)."images/".$name2;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name2, "$uploads_dir2/$name2");

        $ayarkaydet=$db->prepare("UPDATE image SET
            image_adi=:image_adi,
            image2=:image2
            WHERE image_id=1");
        $update=$ayarkaydet->execute(array(
            'image_adi' => $_POST['image_adi'],
            'image2' => $refimgyol2
        ));
    }

    if ($update) {

        Header("Location:../production/image.php?durum=ok");

    } else {

        Header("Location:../production/image.php?durum=no");
    }

}
```

can you help me.
I update one image, the other image is blank

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the same image in your database, because in both queries you use `WHERE image_id=1`.

You currently have `UPDATE` queries like this:

```
UPDATE image 
SET image_adi = :image_adi,
    image1 = :image1
WHERE image_id = 1
```

However, you're uploading new images. I think you want to insert a new row in your database. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO image (image_adi, image)
VALUES (:image_adi, :image)
```

See: [INSERT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Please note that this query is the same in both case, this means you only need one version, not two. You can use a [PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) to call the same version for the two different images.

Comment: no i don't want to add new lines i want to update existing ones